# Subtotal Using Query

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Date      Document No.  Item        Quantity    Price 
1/2/2019    1           ADUKU SS        1       1450
1/2/2019    1           AL GUIDE        1        250
1/2/2019    2           AL FLAT         1         75.65
1/2/2019    2           BATTERY(SMALL)  2          7.52
1/2/2019    2           Item 2          2         72.15
1/2/2019    2           Item3           2         58.75
1/6/2019    3           PAPER WHITE 0.25        1250
```

I need the output as along with subtotal like this:

```
Date    Document No.    Item            Quantity    Price
1/2/2019    1           ADUKU SS            1        1450
1/2/2019    1           AL GUIDE            1         250
1/2/2019    2           AL FLAT 1" 3 MM     1          75.65
1/2/2019    2           BATTERY             2           7.52
1/2/2019    2           Item 2              2          72.15
1/2/2019    2           Item3               2          58.75
1/2/2019                Subtotal                     1914.07
1/6/2019    3           PAPER WHITE         0.25     1250
1/6/2019                Subtotal                     1250
```

How to get the desired output like this using sql query?

I need to get subtotal based on the date.

What I tried so far is as follows :

```
SELECT T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date', T1.[DocNum] AS 'Document No', T0.[Dscription] AS 'Item', 
       T0.[Quantity] AS 'Quantity', T0.[StockPrice] AS 'Inventory Price' 
  FROM [table_1] T0 
 INNER JOIN [table_2] T1 
    ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT T1.[DocDate] as 'Date', NULL,NULL,NULL, SUM(T0.StockPrice) 
  FROM [table_1] T0 
 INNER JOIN [table_2] T1 
    ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] 
 GROUP BY T1.[DocDate]
```

Comment: Can you show your sql effort made so far?

Comment: SELECT T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
T1.[DocNum] AS 'Document No',
 T0.[Dscription] AS 'Item', 
 T0.[Quantity] AS 'Quantity', 
 T0.[StockPrice] AS 'Inventory Price'
 
 FROM  [table_1] T0  INNER  JOIN [table_2] T1  ON  T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry]
 
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT T1.[DocDate] as 'Date',
  NULL,NULL,NULL,
  SUM(T0.StockPrice)
 FROM [table_1] T0  INNER  JOIN [table_2] T1  ON  T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry]
 GROUP BY T1.[DocDate]

Comment: Do not include relevant information in a comment. Instead edit your question and include your code directly in your question.

Comment: The syntax suggests that this is not a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION to your table and the sums:

```
select * 
from documents
union all
select
  date,
  null documentno,
  'Subtotal' item,
  null quantity,
  sum(price) price
from documents
group by date
order by 
  date, 
  case when documentno is null then 1 else 0 end,
  documentno
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/awPBo1vb3GECuLQGBEw7po/0)

Comment: If possible can you explain with this querySELECT T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date', T1.[DocNum] AS 'Document No', T0.[Dscription] AS 'Item', T0.[Quantity] AS 'Quantity', T0.[StockPrice] AS 'Inventory Price' FROM [table_1] T0 INNER JOIN [table_2] T1 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] UNION ALL SELECT T1.[DocDate] as 'Date', NULL,NULL,NULL, SUM(T0.StockPrice) FROM [table_1] T0 INNER JOIN [table_2] T1 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] GROUP BY T1.[DocDate]

Comment: It is logically wrong. I guess it is trying something like the code in my answer but with a join and a union that makes it all wrong.

Comment: I am getting this error, when i execute the query "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because there is no syntax error.

Comment: See the demo link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The syntax suggests that this is not a MySQL query.  Assuming SQL Server (which is consistent with the square braces), uou can use `grouping sets`, but you need an aggregation query:

```
SELECT T1.DocDate, T1.DocNum, T2.Dscription AS Item, 
       SUM(T1.Quantity) AS Quantity,
       T1.StockPrice AS InventoryPrice 
FROM [table_1] T1 INNER JOIN
     [table_2] T2 
     ON T2.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (T1.DocDate, T1.DocNum, T2.Dscription), (T1.DocDate,  T2.Dscription) );
```